# Spacing around negative sign in MS Office's Equation Editor

Tags: equation-editor

If I want to indicate a negative number in the Equation Editor (Office 2007 and onward), I do this:

```
-5
```

Equation Editor renders it nicely, with the hyphen (minus sign?) right close to the number:

[image: negative five]

But if I've got something more complicated, like a vector in polar notation:

```
25\angle-5\degree
```

I get this:

[image]

Which looks more like "twenty five angle minus five degrees" rather than "negative five degrees".

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest solution to this problem that I found is to use "Normal text" mode. Either select the minus sign and press "Normal text" in equation constructor, or put it as `"-"5` instead of simply `-5`

[image]

The result will look like this:

[image]

You can probably bind it to some macro too, but I have no experience with VBA to recommend anything.

Comment: Wow, excellent.  I've searched for a long time for this solution!  Confirmed, both approaches work in Word and PowerPoint 2010.

Answer (score 3):

You can force the issue by wrapping invisible “parentheses” around the number:

```
25\angle\left -5° \right
```

or by using an abstract box that enforces spacing for an unary operator:

```
25\angle\box(4&-)5°
```

The argument to `\box` is documented [here](http://www.unicode.org/notes/tn28/).

Results:

[image]

Comment: Totally odd!  Thanks for that.  How did you figure that out?

Comment: @GregBell: A bit of understanding how such things are determined. The spacing was rather obviously *binary* operator spacing, so the ∠ apparently has "operand" semantics here. Putting everything in `\left` and `\right` was the first idea, since that *had* to change the operator to unary. The other option was by looking through the specification for "unary". The `\box` pretty much allows you to override all parameters that are usually inferred from context, just the argument (4) is a bit unwieldy and hard to remember. Also, the other answer made the minus the wrong character, which annoyed me.